# How to sync and display the tooltips of different google charts?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, charts, google-visualization

I'm creating different google charts on two iframes for comparison purpose. To achieve that I need to sync the mouse click on both the charts and display the tooltips at the particular position of the click.

Although I've achieved syncing the mouse click by using the `chart_2.setSelection(chart_1.getSelection());` method.

But the tooltip doesn't get displayed on the second chart at that specific position:

[image]

The only way to display the tooltip on the second chart is by clicking the chart and then the tooltip gets activated:

[image]

After it gets activated then the tooltip syncs with the first chart and works flawlessly with each click:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to display the tooltip on the second chart without manually activating it but it rather gets displayed with each click on the first chart.

Answer (score 0):

set the following option to cause the tooltip to be displayed on --> `setSelection`

```
var options = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'both'
  }
};
```

see following working snippet,
when the `'ready'` event fires, a selection is made,
to demonstrate the tooltip is displayed

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3'],
    [1, 10, 15, 20, 25],
    [2, 12, 18, 24, 30],
    [3, 14, 21, 28, 35],
    [4, 16, 24, 32, 40]
  ]);

  var options = {
    pointSize: 4,
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'both'
    },
    width: 360
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart.setSelection([{row: 2, column: 1}]);
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: My tooltip's trigger is on 'selection' and I'm using the select listener in order to sync the mouse click events on the two iframes:

`google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'select',function() {
parent.window.iframe_charts.forEach(function(element) {
element.setSelection(chart.getSelection());
});`

where `iframe_charts` is an array that contains the values of all the chart objects.

I want to display the tooltip of both the charts with one click on any chart.

Comment: when you use `setSelection` does the tooltip not appear? (as in the above snippet)

Comment: It actually does, but it only selects one column (i.e legend number #1) and if I use `chart.setSelection([{row: 2, column: 2}]);` then it selects the second column or legend number #2, whereas I want it to select all the columns.